# Infinity while loop C++ char

Tags: c++, while-loop, char

From this C++ code here I try to create an array of char to test either the input is valid or not, as it should be starting with 3 letters with remaining 4 numbers (ex. ABC1234).

**function to test number**

```
bool testNum(char custNum[], int size)
{
    // test first 3 characters for alphabetic letters
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 5; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(custNum[i]))
            return false;
    }
    
    // test remaining 4 characters for numeric digits
    for (int i = 3; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(custNum[i]))
            return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

**main program**

```
int main() 
{
    const int SIZE = 8;
    char customerNum[SIZE];
    
    // loop if customer number not valid
    while (!(testNum(customerNum, SIZE)))
    {

        cout<<"Enter customer number [LLLNNNN]\n(L = Letters | N = Number): ";
        cin.getline(customerNum, SIZE);
        
        // determine a valid customerNum
        if (testNum(customerNum, SIZE))
        {
            cout<<endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
            {
                cout<<customerNum[i];
            }
            cout<<"is a valid customer number!\n";
        }
        
        else 
        {
            cout<<endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
                cout<<customerNum[i];
            }
            cout<<"is not a valid customer number!\n";
            cout<<"(example of customer number = ABC1234)\n\n";
        }
    } // if user input >= size, somehow the program will loop (ex: 12345678)
    
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is in the while loop, if for instance I try to put an input with size more than the defined size (ex. 12345678) it will print output:

```
Enter customer number [LLLNNNN]
(L = Letters | N = Number): 12345678

1234567 is not a valid customer number!
(example of customer number = ABC1234)

Enter customer number [LLLNNNN]
(L = Letters | N = Number):
 234567 is not a valid customer number!
(example of customer number = ABC1234)

Enter customer number [LLLNNNN]
(L = Letters | N = Number):
 234567 is not a valid customer number!
(example of customer number = ABC1234)

Enter customer number [LLLNNNN]
(L = Letters | N = Number):
 234567 is not a valid customer number!
```

after it prints the output entered then it continues to print an infinite loop, as the program wouldn't stop for the user to input new values. Can someone tell why this happens?

Comment: use `std::string`. You cannot put more than `7` characters + null terminator in a `char[8]`. Also you are testing input before the user entered any input

Comment: Yeah your are right, in char[8], if I put more than 7 characters it will discard the rest. From the output I did test input '12345678' and it only print '1234567'. 

Question is why on the next iteration the program does not let me to input any value as it just goes on continuously. For example if I input '1234567', it will loop back as the value is not valid and the program will actually stop and ask for new input.

Also on the next iteration why it only prints ' 234567' not same as the first iteration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[When the input line is too long, `getline` sets the `failbit` of `cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline), causing [each future read from `cin` to yield an empty string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedInputFunction).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with using std::string for anything related with text.
When looking for patterns in texts nothing beats regular expressions, they're well documented and not unimportantly well tested :)

And for arrays use std::array instead of the a[] notation. It prevents a lot of problems in the long run.

In this case testing for a valid customer number use something like this:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

bool is_valid_customer_number(const std::string& text)
{
    // the next regex matches exactly 3 letters {3}, followed by exactly 4 {4} numbers
    static std::regex expression{ "([a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9]{4})" };
    std::cmatch matches;

    // the next line returns true if the regex matches, 
    // the matches variable is unused but needed to make the call
    return std::regex_match(text.c_str(), matches, expression);
};

main()
{
    assert(is_valid_customer_number("ABC1234"));
    assert(!is_valid_customer_number("1BCA234"));
}
```

I hope this helps you forward on your journey of discovery :)